# Creating a DynamicModule with multiple variables created automatically

Tags: dynamic, slider

I want to create a `DynamicModule` that has several variables that were automatically created. For example:

```
DynamicModule[{a1, a2, 
  a3}, {{Slider[Dynamic[a1]], Slider[Dynamic[a2]], 
   Slider[Dynamic[a3]]}, {Dynamic[a1], Dynamic[a2], Dynamic[a3]}}]
```

here there are three different sliders which all have different variables associated with it. Since I later want to adjust the number of sliders and variables dynamically, I basically want to automatize this such that I can create multiple sliders each with its own variable.

So I tried to build the variables, but this totally fails:

```
   DynamicModule[ToExpression@Table["a" <> ToString@x, {x, 1, 3}], 
 Slider[Dynamic[#]] & /@ Table["a" <> ToString@x, {x, 1, 3}], 
 Dynamic@Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString@x], {x, 1, 3}]]
```

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

Kuba and Holistic pointed out some issues with the original answer. This new version addresses those issues:
To insert the built variable names in such a way that they're not affected by previous values, we need to use the three argument form of [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) to wrap the resulting expression in [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html). After inserting them into `DynamicModule`, we can [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) the whole thing again.

```
With[
 {vars = Table[
    ToExpression["a" <> ToString@i, InputForm, Inactive], {i, 5}]},
 ReleaseHold@Activate@Hold@DynamicModule[
     vars,
     {Slider[Dynamic[#]] & /@ vars,
      Slider[Dynamic[#]] &@vars[[1]],
      Slider[Dynamic[Evaluate@vars[[1]]]],
      Dynamic /@ vars, 
      Dynamic@vars[[1]],
      Dynamic@a1}
     ]
 ]
```

The code above also demonstrates two ways how to solve the issue encountered by Holistic: `Slider@Dynamic@vars[[1]]` does not work as expected. The reason for this is once again a `Hold...` attribute (`HoldFirst` of [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) in this case). To get `vars[[i]]` to evaluate before getting wrapped by `Dynamic`, we can either call `Evaluate` or simply make a pure function and apply that to `vars[[1]]`.

## Old way

One way to achieve what you're after is to generate the list of variables before and insert them into `DynamicModule` using `With`:

```
With[
 {vars = Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString@i], {i, 5}]},
 DynamicModule[
  vars,
  {
   Slider[Dynamic[#]] & /@ vars,
   Dynamic /@ vars
   }
  ]
 ]
```

The problem with your approach arises due to the following two properties of `DynamicModule`: It has attribute `HoldAll` and it localized the variables. Combined, this means that `DynamicModule` doesn't see the variables at the time of first evaluation, resulting in them not being localized.

(You could also try to simply put an `Evaluate` around the variable declaration to at least get valid symbols to localize, but you'll run into other issues depending on how you use your variables later.)

Comment: Ah ok, I see! Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: One quick follow-up questions: Can you explain why I am not able to access these values like this? `With[{vars = Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString@i], {i, 2}]}, 
 DynamicModule[
  vars, {Slider[Dynamic[vars[[1]]]], Dynamic[vars[[1]]], 
   Dynamic[vars[[1]]]}]]`

Comment: @Kuba: Ah ok! I think I found a way to make it work: `With[{vars = Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString@i], {i, 2}]}, 
 DynamicModule[{blub = vars}, {Slider[Dynamic[blub[[1]]]], 
   Slider[Dynamic[blub[[2]]]], Dynamic[blub[[1]]], 
   Dynamic[blub[[2]]]}]]`

Comment: @Kuba & holistic: Thanks for pointing out those issues. I have updated the answer to address them.

Comment: @Mathe172: Thanks for making an update! Works very well.